# Issue Of Integration Express Checkout with java play framework

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Edit: format

I am trying to intigration `paypal express` checkout in `java play framework` Almost it's done But In `Json` Response Which is given by `paypal` it include approval_url :

> "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd\u003d_express-checkout\u0026token\u003dEC-7*******...

In this URL include

> \u003d before _express-checkout , \u0026 before token word and \u003d
>   before token response key...

What that string mean??? I need URL like

> "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7***************"...

How can I get this???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a sandbox transaction this is the url that you should be using for Express Checkout:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=

Here is the documentation in the PayPal Developer site:

[Express Checkout Setting Up a Transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#id0832BA0605Z)

Below is the link to Express Checkout Sample Code: 
[PayPal Code Wizard](http://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/code.php)